# UseSpa() returns index.html from API instead of 404

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application, pipeline

By default .UseSpa() in startup.cs catches every request that arrives to its point of the pipeline, and tries to handle it as a request to the SPA main page

I want to keep 404 for for my API calls at route /api/* just in case when typo in api url is made it my logger would log 404 and and not like "Error Code: 200 Message: Http failure during parsing for https://localhost:5001/api/non-existing-api-should-give-404" (because it got index.html in response)

Already spend over day on this and I can't find solution :( UseSpa() seems to overwrite any not matched endpoint. Any ideas how to solve it?

Here is basic configure from Startup.cs, problem is in Production Environment.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, please share enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @Rena code is just basic code from even sample app. I've added sample. So, in this scenario how do I get 404 for /api/* calls instead index.html from SPA?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, check my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `UseSpa` middlware is a catch-all, and any request that gets to that point will always have the default SPA page returned. This means any request to a route that hasn't yet found a controller will always return the default SPA page, and not throw a 404.

What you will want to do it only call `UseSpa()` if the route is not prefixed with `/api`. Which essentially lets any requests that start with`/api` skip past that point.

**Change:**

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    //...
});
```

**To:**

```
app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{
    builder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        //...
    });
});
```

This will let any request that starts with `/api` past that point, and if no other middleware or routes are matched, a `404` will be returned.

Comment: I've tried that but still it does not work. It seems to ignore MapWhen...!StartsWith whenever I add UseSpa() inside. When replacing builder.UseSpa(...) with builder.Run(async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not API call")); it works correctly and displays 404 for not matched api routes.

Comment: does this code run correctly on your machine ? Because it looks as it should work and it does when you replace UseSpa with something else (like my Run example above). But with UseSpa you wont get 404 for not existing api call, but index.html from spa, even if its inside MapWhen not StartsWith"(/api"). I'm testing it on dotnet 5.

Comment: It works well in my project. Of course it will return 404 for not existing api. I think you do not read my answer carefully. The reason for why not return 404 is because you use `app.UseSpa`. You could use `app.MapWhen` to avoid using `app.UseSpa` for /api/* calls. Only if the reuqest do not start with api, the `app.UseSpa` could be called.

Comment: My mistake... I've used app.UseSpa() inside MapWhen instead builder.UseSpa() - code compilies, but this stupid mistake took me so many hours... I have to look more careful what I use i that kind of function. Thanks @Rena ! You are awesome!